# I want to build an app in Python in which I have to detect while-key-is-pressed

Tags: python, input, keyboard, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Hello folks I am building a car remote controller on raspbian  using python 
but what I want is while 'w' key is pressed i want to call `forward()` but the problem is how to get the thing **While-key-is-pressed()**  thimg python
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*curses*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) to achieve what you want on *Raspberry-Pi*. Curses is an graphical API for CLI programs, you can achieve much more than just detect key events.

In the following example we print "Up is pressed;" to the screen when the <kbd>↑</kbd> key is pressed. We stop the program when <kbd>q</kbd> is pressed.

```
import curses

def example_curses(stdscr):
    stdscr.keypad(1)
    while 1:
        key = stdscr.getch()
        if key == curses.KEY_UP: 
            stdscr.addstr("Up is pressed; ")
            # call forward()
        elif key == ord('q'):
            break


def main():
    curses.wrapper(example_curses)
    print("'q' has pressed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

We also used `stdscr.keypad(1)` because it helps us to detect presses of special keys:

> Terminals usually return special keys, such as the cursor keys or
>   navigation keys such as Page Up and Home, as a multibyte escape
>   sequence. While you could write your application to expect such
>   sequences and process them accordingly, curses can do it for you,
>   returning a special value such as `curses.KEY_LEFT`. To get curses to do
>   the job, you’ll have to enable keypad mode.

Comment: actually this not what i want. I need a functionality of while-a-key-is-pressed.

Comment: This is what it is, `while stdscr.getch() == key` is ~ equals to while-a-key-is-pressed